# How to pass a variable using intent extra from one activity to another and then return it to the first activity to the same variable

Tags: android-intent

Hi i'm using intent to switch activity's and putextra to pass a variable. The problem is i need to share a IP address (as a string) from the 1st activity to the second, then from the second to the terd. If i now that i'm on the terd try to go to the 2 and pass the IP address to the same variable on the second activity it won't alow it.

Is there a way i can share this recourse with all my activities without intent?